# The Big Bang theory

Tags: big-bang

According to big bang theory the whole universe was formed by this big explosion 
and it gets bigger and bigger

Does that mean it has limits? and what do you think we can found beyond all that ?

Comment: This is I believe what I call well , an impossible answer. We can never say for sure that well Universe is infinite. Plus, universe means everything. Universe is equal to everything that exists.

Comment: The limit of the visible universe is simply the visible remnant of the beginning of time. Beyond that the universe can be as big as it likes to be, we could not tell.

Answer (score 0):

The Big Bang is not thought to be an "explosion", but an "[expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space)" that included "[inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29)", analogous to dots on the surface of a balloon, that get further apart as the balloon expands. No dot on the balloon is considered to be the central dot, all dots move away from each other.

The universe is considered infinite, and consequently, so it was for the